# Straight line through multiple points on graph

Tags: matlab, math

Can someone please help me figure out how you can plot a straight line through multiple points? By that, i dont mean passing a line through two points, or point that do lay on a straight line. I want to plot a line that is of minimum distance from every point. Something like this:

[image: line_through_points]

Comment: That's called fitting. And in this case it is specially easy, it is a linear fitting. If you search for it, I am quite sure you will find several posts showing you how to do it x)

Comment: You should check out the `lsline` function.

Comment: Not minimum distance from every point.  Least squares fitting minimizes the sum of squared error between every point and the line; hence the name.

Comment: You should ask this question in Mathematics.SE to be positive, but I'm pretty sure that the least-squares line also minimizes the distances between the points and the line.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few options used in image processing, where it's often necessary to find best fit lines (and best fit curves, shapes, etc.) in the presence of significant noise and/or outlier points. You would need to consider the appropriateness and computation time of each method.

1. Least squares fit - standard technique to find a best fit line through multiple points, but can yield a poor fit if there are few points and one or more outliers. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares
2. RANSAC - random sampling and consensus; especially nice in higher dimensions. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC
3. Hough line fit - good if you have a number of points close to a line, and a number of noise points as well. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform

A least squares linear fit would probably be the best to try first.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lsline.html

http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/least-squares-fitting.html

Answer (score 0):

It's usually called a "line of best fit".

http://www.matrixlab-examples.com/polynomials.html

Look at using [`polyfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html).